How to auto indent?
Say I'm in foo.py and I want to paste something into the docstr of function f:
something:
foo
bar

def f():
    """
    
    """

My current workflow (evil normal mode, in python buffer):

Move cursor below first """
Hit TAB to move the cursor 4 characters to the right
Hit p

Now two question arise:

Only the first line is indented. For me this is fundamentally wrong and I'm forced to manually indent. Yet in regards of such an operation's daily impact, there must be a reason, but what?
Shouldn't my second step TAB be automated?

Result:
def f():
    """
    foo
bar 
    """

Or should I rethink my workflow and look at CI/CD tools e.g. black,yapf formatters etc.?

I would forego the first TAB: just paste, then C-x C-x to reestablish the region, then TAB to indent the whole region (but evil may be different - I wouldn't know).

If you install the package apheleia from MELPA, it will format on save, with the condition to have black installed.
